# Custom domain mapping php/nginx

Tags: php, nginx, dns

We have a web application where users gets their own subdomain created upon registration. now they want to map their own domains to our subdomains.

for example:

- customerdomain1.com will work as sub1.mydomain.com
- www.customerdomain2.com will work as sub2.mydomain.com
- www.customerdomain3.com will work as sub3.mydomain.com

On that scenario, customer's domain name should always stays on the browser.

This is our hosting/ Software setup:

PHP, Nginx, SSL, VPS with dedicated IP.

N.B. Another thing need to be consider is, our sub-domain will have wildcard ssl but customers domain will not have SSL always.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add the customers domain to the server_name in your subdomain config.

```
server_name customerdomain1.com sub1.mydomain.com;
```

If you have your own VPS with a dedicated IP, why not add Dehydrated and add SSL certificates with Let's Encrypt?

Comment: thanks for the reply. i tried exactly as u said above but the issue is, when i type customerdomain1.com its just redirect to sub1.mydomain.com. i want to address to be remain customerdomain1.com. and regarding ssl, i didnt understand what u mean by Dehydrated

Comment: sorry, I missed the link for Dehydrated. https://github.com/lukas2511/dehydrated (It's a tool to generate SSL certificates from Let's Encrypt)

Comment: multiple domains works for me, might be something in your nginx config. Can you post it?

Comment: Thank @Esuk for your help. here is my server block. https://pastebin.com/tbC09BhX